# How to give bootstrap columns background images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just wondering how to give a col in bootstrap a background image, so it will only appear in that column and not the entire page. I'm trying to do this so I can leave my navbar transparent and only have the columns below it have a background pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to give the col a class name or id for example

```
<div class="col-xs-3 myImage">
```

You can place the image in the container itself using the example below.
In your css you need to firstly make sure that the image is contained in the column so set the max-width parameter.

```
.myImage{
display:block;
max-width:100%; // change this is you need it to be smaller
background-image:url('yourimagefoldername/imagefilename.jpg');
background-size: cover; // contain might suite you better
background-position:center; // this can be change to top, bottom or wherever
}
```

That is pretty much all you need to do.